# Error while Download excel file using vf page

Tags: visualforce

[image]when i downloaded into system in libre office and wps office the excel file is opening but in Ms Excel the file is throwing error

### vf page

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" 
           id="pge" 
           standardController="Order" 
           extensions="OrderExcelGenerationController"  
           applyHtmlTag="false" 
           applyBodyTag="false"
           showHeader="false" 
           contenttype="application/vnd.ms-excel#orderForm.xls">
    
    {!xmlHeader}
    
    <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
              xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
              xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
              xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
              xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"
              xmlns:xdr="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/spreadsheetDrawing"
              xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" 
              xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
        
        <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
            <WindowHeight>8535</WindowHeight>
            <WindowWidth>12345</WindowWidth>
            <WindowTopX>480</WindowTopX>
            <WindowTopY>90</WindowTopY>
            <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
            <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
        </ExcelWorkbook>
        
        <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
            <Author></Author>
            <LastAuthor></LastAuthor>
            <Company></Company>
            <Version>11.6360</Version>
        </DocumentProperties>
        <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
            
            <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="100">
                
                <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="0" ss:Hidden="1"></Column>
                <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="200"></Column>
                <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="2" ss:Width="200"></Column>
                <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="3" ss:StyleID="" ss:Width="150"></Column>
                <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="4" ss:StyleID="" ss:Width="150"></Column>
                <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="5" ss:Width="150"></Column>
                <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="6" ss:Width="150"></Column>
                <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="7" ss:Width="150"></Column>
                
                
                <Row ss:Height="40">
                    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">AUD</Data></Cell>
                    <Cell ss:MergeAcross="5" ss:StyleID="s1">
                        <Data ss:Type="String">ORDER FORM</Data>
                    </Cell>
                </Row>
                
                
                <Row ss:Height="20">
                    <Cell>
                        <Data ss:Type="String"></Data>
                    </Cell>
                </Row>
                
                
                <Row ss:Height="20">
                    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">AUD</Data></Cell>
                    <Cell ss:MergeAcross="">
                        <Data ss:Type="String">HOTEL</Data>
                    </Cell>
              </Row>

            </Table>
        </Worksheet>
    </Workbook>
    <apex:outputText value="{!endFileXML}" escape="false" /> 
    
</apex:page>
```

### Controller

```
public with sharing class OrderExcelGenerationController {
    
    public string accountName {get;set;}
    public string endfile {get;set;}    
    public Set<String> type {get;set;}
    public String endFileXML {get;set;}
    public OrderExcelGenerationController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        
        endFileXML = '</Workbook>';
        orderId=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('orderId');
        //Id orderId='8010T000000D31JQAS';
        order = [SELECT Id,Name,Account.Name,Account.ShippingStreet,Account.ShippingCity,Account.ShippingState,Account.ShippingPostalCode,Account.ShippingCountry FROM Order WHERE Id=:orderId];
        
        xmlheader ='<?xml version="1.0"?><?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>';        
        endfile = '</Workbook>';
```

### lighnting component - js

```
             var result=response.getReturnValue();
                    
                    let downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
                    downloadLink.download = result.orderFileName+'.xlsx';
                    downloadLink.href = 'data:application/excel;base64,'+result.orderFileContent;
                    downloadLink.click();
```

---

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That's not an error, just a warning. What happens if you click 'Yes'?

Comment: Problems came up in the following areas during Load:
Style
Table
Strict Parse Error

Comment: if i click 'Yes'? means on top i have posted another image that strict parse error and style and table error it is showing.

Comment: Have you checked the specified error log?

Comment: i have checked error log but i havent noticed any error. i can see the excel output in libre office and wps office. but i am facing error only in Microsoft excel only. Pls help me on this issue